# How do you rob a black market in Dishonored 2

Tags: dishonored-2

How do you get into a black market and what do I do once inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored-2/Robbing_Black_Markets) done by IGN which has a video as well as text instructions on how to achieve Robbing all black markets.

Here is a direct link to the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66GdM_Jn_jM)

> **Edge of the World**
>
> Upstairs to the right of the black market you see an infested
> building. Make your way all the way to the top where the Nestkeeper
> is. In a glass aquarium is the black market key. Jump down from the
> window, turn right and enter the black market from Mindy's yard
>
> **The Clockwork Mansion**
>
> Enter the train station through the roof and
> steal the Whale Oil Tank inside. Walk through the wall of light turn
> right and leave the Oil Tank in front of the black market stairs for
> now. Look up in front of the stairs and find a way to get to the
> balcony at the top. Go all the way down into the basement where two
> women plan to blow up the wall. Listen to their conversation and take
> them out. Now take the gate key on the shelf and get your third Whale
> Oil Tank that you left upstairs. Put it next to the other two
> downstairs and blow up the wall. That's it for black market robbery
> number two.
>
> **The Royal Conservatory**
>
> Go inside the black market that which is located in the first building
> to the left. Just before you go to the shopkeeper, you see a gated
> window on your left. Shoot the red cable and grab the wheel that is
> just a few steps from the window. Take the wheel to the canal. Next to
> the big gate you can place the wheel and open it. Swim through and
> climb the chain to your next black marked rob.  Dust District
>
> Next to the black market in Dust District downstairs, there is a small
> crack that you can crawl through. Go through it and turn left. Through
> one of the gated windows you can see a blocked door. Shoot the
> barricade, walk into the black marked and enter the room you just
> opened. Look for a calender at the wall and look for the circled
> number in the 4th row. The code for the black market always starts
> with 4 and the last two numbers are the ones circled in row 4.
>
> **The Grand Palace**
>
> Get a code from the back of the Winslow store and use it at the gate
> left from the store. Steal the boat key from a woman that i leaning
> there and backtrack to the harbor. Inside the shipe you can listen to
> an audiograph that gives you access to the black market. Return to the
> woman you just took the key from and get access to the black market
> door next to her.
>
> **Death to the Empress**
>
> To the left of the Courier early on in the mission, you can get
> through an almost blocked up alley. Turn right and smash the bottles
> on the shelf to get the warehouse key. Go to the black market next to
> the courier, exit through the back door and jump down to find the
> warehouse gate. Climb up the chain and your last black market robbery
> is done.

Comment: Great, that helped a lot, thanks. Should I avoid the shop owner?

Comment: If he spots you he will close shop. And with it the chance to purchase any upgrades from that store.